# is there a way to get a list of Power BI refresh failures through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powerbi

We have many workspaces and reports across our organization. What we need is a way of running a PowerShell script to get the list of datasets/dataflows refresh failures in like a CSV format or something.
Is this doable? can anyone share some tips etc. please?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can use the [REST API for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-refresh-history-in-group). There is no direct support for retrieving the history directly with a dedicated [PowerShell cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.data), but you can use `Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod` to much the same effect.

Comment: many thanks! is this doable from PowerShell?

Comment: Yes, check my second link.